# How do I disable the calendar events section in GNOME Shell's clock applet?

Tags: gnome, calendar, clock

I'm running gnome-shell 3.2.0 and when I click the clock applet in the middle of the top panel, the following shows up:

[image: Screenshot of gnome-shell calendar applet]

I have no need for the entire right part, right of the dotted line, which is dedicated to the "Online Accounts" integration with evolution's calendar. Is there a way to remove/disable it, so I can just have the date part of the calendar applet (left of the dotted vertical line)?

I just like to browse the dates to see how many days are left in the month and stuff like that. I use Google's web interface for my "Calendaring".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Edit: This is now obsolete, an extension has been written for this: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/153/nothingtodo/

There's no configuration value for this, it's hard-coded in at the moment, but it's easy enough to change:

```
gksudo gedit /usr/share/gnome-shell/js/ui/panel.js
```

Find the line that reads:

```
this._dateMenu = new DateMenu.DateMenuButton({ showEvents: true });
```

And simply change `true` to `false`

Then restart GNOME Shell by pressing Alt-F2 and entering `r`

A useful resource for reference (see components section): http://blog.fpmurphy.com/2011/05/more-gnome-shell-customization.html

Edit: For anyone who's interested, here's the end result:

[image: GNOME Shell calendar without agenda]

Comment: Brilliant; thanks a lot! :-) I would give 2 up-votes if I could, for providing that useful customization link. Thanks again!

Comment: Just curious, but would you also know how to make the resulting calendar window more centered?

Comment: Sure: in `js/ui/dateMenu.js` change `let menuAlignment = 0.25` to `let menuAlignment = 0.5`

Comment: I was going to ask this but I thought it would be too much. Never doubt the community again! ;-)

Comment: Works perfectly in Wheezy... but that's not working Jessie with gnome-shell 3.14.2. Is there any other way to do it in gnome-shell 3.14?

Comment: Are you referring to the manual tweak or the NothingToDo extension not working?

Answer (score 3):

There is an extension for that called Nothing To Do (search extensions.gnome.org).

Comment: Nice, thanks. This is the link to it: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/153/nothingtodo/